# Disable a function with click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HERE'S MY [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/98wy9ss9/3/)**

I have one home page with smoothscroll wheel script. 
And I have a div "about" which is visible on click with a button.
The problem is that I would like my smoothscroll work also on my div about. But it doesn't work... The div doesn't scroll... Also, when the div "about" is open, I would like the div "home" no scroll.

```
$('button').click(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {

    $("#about").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
    $("body").css({"overflow": "auto"});


    $(this).removeClass("clicked");
  } else {

    $("#about").css({"visibility": "visible"});
    $("body").css({"overflow": "hidden"});

    $(this).addClass("clicked");
  }
});


$("body").smoothWheel();
```

Comment: by the way, it's `<br/>` or `<br>` - never `</br>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#about').smoothWheel();` whenever you need to smooth scroll. It will automatically re-assign it to the `#about` and remove it from the `body`.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/98wy9ss9/4/)

```
$('button').click(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {

    $("#about").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
    $("body").css({"overflow": "auto"}).smoothWheel();;


    $(this).removeClass("clicked");
  } else {

    $("#about").css({"visibility": "visible"}).smoothWheel();
    $("body").css({"overflow": "hidden"});

    $(this).addClass("clicked");
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem s that when you click several times, the script smoothWheel is added each time. So I have severals smoothWheel, and my smooth effect on body is really really speed...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body,#about").smoothWheel();
```

You forgot to add #about. Replace it like above to have smoothWheel for both body and div.